# Icon Field on List

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I load label and icon from mysql database.

and i'd like to create a list with label and icon field.

So I try to do something like that but it doesn't work indeed each line contain label but icon is empty.

```
var xmllisteFamille:XMLList = XML(event.result).famille;
                var xmlListCollFami = new XMLListCollection(xmllisteFamille);
                for each (var item:Object in xmlListCollFami){
                    var vbox:VBox = new VBox;
                    vbox.label = item.sdfNom;
                    trace(vbox.label);
                    vbox.percentHeight=100;
                    vbox.percentWidth=100;
                    var xmlItem2:XMLList = item.commDent;
                    if(xmlItem2.length()>0){

                        /*
                            var listAcc:List = new List();
                            listAcc.percentHeight = 100;
                            listAcc.percentWidth =100;
                            listAcc.labelField = "name";
                            listAcc.dataProvider = xmlItem2;
                            vbox.addChild(listAcc);
                            accOnglet1.addChild(vbox); */
                        var urlImageRoot : urlManager = new urlManager();
                        var urlRootDental:String = urlImageRoot.urlDental();
                        trace(urlRootDental);
                        var list:Array = new Array();
                        var object:Object;

                        var xmlListdetail:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(xmlItem2);
                        for each (var item2:Object in xmlListdetail)
                        {

                            object = new Object();
                            // -- --
                            object.label = item2.name;

                            var rootIcon:String= "http://127.0.0.1:10088/Sys/OEMySQL/Dental/"+item2.photo;
                            trace("rootIcon " + rootIcon);

                            object.icon = rootIcon;

                            trace("object.icon " + object.icon);

                            list.push(object);
                        }

                        /* var aNode:XML;
                        for each (aNode in xmlItem2)
                        {
                            object = new Object();
                            // -- --
                            object.label = aNode.name;
                            object.icon = new urlManager().urlDental()+aNode.photo;
                            list.push(object);
                        } */

                        var arrList:ArrayList;

                        arrList = new ArrayList(list);
                        var listAcc:List = new List();
                        listAcc.percentHeight = 100;
                        listAcc.percentWidth =100;
                        listAcc.labelField = "label";
                        listAcc.iconField="icon";
                        //listAcc.dataProvider = xmlItem2;
                        listAcc.dataProvider = arrList;
                        vbox.addChild(listAcc);
                        accOnglet1.addChild(vbox); 
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

I hope that you can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I had to create an itemrenderer and add it in as3 to my list.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

it may be crossdomain issue

you need to know if flash player requires crossdomain.xml in this case

use charles proxy to check what exactly you are sending to server (request) and getting back from server (response)

[charles proxy website](http://www.charlesproxy.com)